VS Code don't run on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I am using VS Code on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and on June 5, 2024 it was updated, but when I start the VS Code application it opens and after 2 seconds it closes, I rebooted my PC and tried to update again and it keeps doing the same thing, is there a way to fix it?

Solution if you installed vscode by Snap Store:
I found a solution by executing the command sudo snap revert code and it worked for me.
References:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78585138/visual-studio-code-crashes-on-ubuntu-22-04-4-lts

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
